# Unable to convert to numbers from DataFrame columns when characters are appearing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file, which contains latitudes and longitudes in degree-minute format (contains degree symbol also). When I load this CSV file, a question mark symbol (?) is appearing in place of the degree symbol. I tried by adding encoding='utf-8' and encoding='latin1', still question mark symbol (?) is appearing.

After loading this file, I need to convert these latitude/longitude points to degree format (without any symbol). What is the correct way to do this?

Link to the input file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NnfN9lcezuQCq7p-sbiZEIxxmWEn4pQc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can read your file using `encoding='latin1'`. You can convert as decimal degrees in a vectorized way using:

```
df['LAT'] = df['LAT_DM'].str[:2].astype(int) + df['LAT_DM'].str[3:].astype(int).div(60)
df['LONG'] = df['LONG'].str[:2].astype(int) + df['LONG_DM'].str[3:].astype(int).div(60)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  LAT_DM LONG_DM        LAT       LONG
0  28°10   97°05  28.166667  97.083333
1  28°21   97°18  28.350000  97.300000
2  28°30   97°25  28.500000  97.416667
3  28°42   97°35  28.700000  97.583333
4  28°55   97°45  28.916667  97.750000
5  28°54   97°45  28.900000  97.750000
6  28°74   97°12  29.233333  97.200000
7  28°50   97°40  28.833333  97.666667
```